# addAssertion() not recognizing string value of "Contains" type

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a groovy script that I've added code to to check if a value exists in an XML response I'm getting within SoapUI.  I've been dealing with this for a few days and could use some help.

Here is the code:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.RestRequestStepFactory

// read your request template
def requestFile = new File("C:/XMLRequestScript/file.xml");

// parse it as xml
def requestXml = new XmlHolder(requestFile.text)

// get the current testCase to add testSteps later
def tc = testRunner.testCase;

// get the testStep as template to create the other requests
def tsTemplate = tc.getTestStepByName("Template");

// loop to create # of testSteps for each application
for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
// xpath expression to get applicationNumber attribute in root node
def xpathNodeAttr = "/*/@ApplicationNumber";

// get the root node attribute applicationNumber throught an XPATH
int appId = Integer.parseInt(requestXml.getNodeValue(xpathNodeAttr));

// add 1 to appId
appId++;

// set the value again in the attribute
requestXml.setNodeValue(xpathNodeAttr,appId);

// create next testStepName for new Application
def testStepName = "TestStep_ApplicationNumber_" + String.valueOf(appId)
log.info testStepName;
log.info testStepName.getClass().getName()
log.info tc.getClass().getName()

// create a new testStepConfig
def testStepFactory = new RestRequestStepFactory();
def testStepConfig = testStepFactory.createConfig( tsTemplate.getTestRequest(), testStepName )

// add the new testStep to TestCase
def newTestStep = tc.insertTestStep( testStepConfig, -1 ) 

// set the request
newTestStep.getTestRequest().setRequestContent(requestXml.getXml())   

// add Assertions here
def assertion = tc.getTestStepByName(newTestStep.toString()).addAssertion("Contains")
if (assertion.contains("Champion5")) {
    newTestStep.addAssertion("Champion5")
    log.info("REST response assertion created into: " + newTestStep)
} else {
    log.info("REST response assertion not found in " + newTestStep)
}
if (assertion.contains("Challenger5")) {
    newTestStep.addAssertion("Challenger5")
    log.info("REST response assertion created into: " + newTestStep)
} else {
log.info("REST response assertion not found in " + newTestStep)
}

// execute the request 
newTestStep.run(testRunner, context)
```

}

In the section above called "// add Assertions here", the line of code that I'm having a problem with is:

```
def assertion = tc.getTestStepByName(newTestStep.toString()).addAssertion("Contains")
```

The error states:

```
Thu Sep 18 14:27:57 CDT 2014:ERROR:An error occurred [Cannot invoke method addAssertion() on null object], see error log for details
```

My understanding is that I have to pass an Assertion Type that is contained in the SoapUI GUI and just put it in as a string value in order to check if the values that I'm checking are asserted.

Any suggestions/direction would be appreciated.  I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: my first answer was not correct, I think that now it's more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your are calling the function `tc.getTestStepByName(String name)` with a wrong name, because the `newTestStep.toString()` doesn't return the Test step name instead it returns the class name (it really returns `'classname' + '@' + 'Integer.toHexString(hashCode())'` if it's not override it, see [Object.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)) .

Anyway what you want is to add an assertion for a test step which is just created so add the assertion directly to it instead to find it by name, use:

`def assertion = newTestStep.addAssertion("Contains")`

instead of:

`def assertion = tc.getTestStepByName(newTestStep.toString()).addAssertion("Contains")`

The second problem you have is that you're using the `assertion` incorrectly. The `assertion` object in your case is an instance of [SimpleContainsAssertion](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/assertions/basic/SimpleContainsAssertion.html) and `contains()` method doesn't exist in this class, to set the string to check in contains assert use `setToken()` method, I think that you need this to add the two assertions:

```
def assertion = newTestStep.addAssertion("Contains")
// add token to check
assertion.setToken("Champion5") 
// change assert name in order to avoid the popup
// when we create the second one.
assertion.setName("CONTAINS 1")
// create a second assertion
assertion = newTestStep.addAssertion("Contains")
assertion.setToken("Challenger5")
assertion.setName("CONTAINS 2")
```

instead of :

```
// add Assertions here
def assertion = tc.getTestStepByName(newTestStep.toString()).addAssertion("Contains")
if (assertion.contains("Champion5")) {
    newTestStep.addAssertion("Champion5")
    log.info("REST response assertion created into: " + newTestStep)
} else {
    log.info("REST response assertion not found in " + newTestStep)
}
if (assertion.contains("Challenger5")) {
    newTestStep.addAssertion("Challenger5")
    log.info("REST response assertion created into: " + newTestStep)
} else {
    log.info("REST response assertion not found in " + newTestStep)
}
```

This code will result creating this two asserts, one named "CONTAINS 1" and check that response contains the string "Champion5", and a second one named "CONTAINS 2" and check that response contains the string "Challenge5".

Hope this helps,

Comment: Yes.  Thank you.  I guess what I'm not sure about is in the API from SoapUI I'm not seeing what classes are best to use and how to go about choosing them.  I got the code from googling and it seemed to work for them but apparently I had the wrong info.  Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks again for all your time and help.  Regards.

Comment: yes at first maybe it's not intuitive, however you can take a look at documentation and samples in the web: http://www.soapui.org/ and at the api https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui to see methods, classes... And of course coding as you do :)